# Input in sweetalert 2 not typeable or cannot be typed on in materializecss modal

Tags: javascript, css, materialize, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have modal in which when i click add bills button it will popup the sweetalert2, the code provided below came from their documentation, so i think there is no problem with the codes, anyways, my problem is that the input cannot by type-able and it is just like disabled, is this a problemn in materializecss side?

P.s I am using a materializecss css framework, and i also read an article which has the same problem with me in the bootstrap framework.

https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/374

```
    $(".btnAddBills").click(function(event) {  
swal.mixin({
    input: 'text',
    confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
    showCancelButton: true,
    progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
}).queue([
{
    title: 'Question 1',
    text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy'
},
'Question 2',
'Question 3'
]).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        swal({
            title: 'All done!',
            html:
            'Your answers: <pre><code>' +
            JSON.stringify(result.value) +
            '</code></pre>',
            confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!'
        })
    }
})
```

});

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**The Problem**
The issue is from bootstrap modal accessibility control code which can be found here [Modal Accessibility Tab Control](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/a404ac33bb9e78323b84d0840735445579634b9e), it enforces focus on the Bootstrap modal whenever it loses focus to another element( in this case SweetAlert Modal) in the page.

**WorkAround**
It's as simple as removing the focus event.

For Bootstrap 4 
add this code to your JS

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {};
```

For Bootstrap 3 add this code to your JS

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(document).off('focusin.modal');
});
```

Comment: What is the solution for sweetalert2 pop up modal?

Answer (score 12):

For bootstrap 5,

Declare your modal with `data-bs-focus="false"`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="global_modal_fullscreen" data-bs-focus="false" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
...
```

Answer (score 5):

**Removing tabindex**

Another solution to that situation is to remove the `tabindex` attribute from the bootstrap modal, that will prevent the sweetAlert2 modal looses the focus.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered untypeable input issue with SweetAlert2 within a Material-UI Dawer in React? Here's a fix:

The problem lies in MUI Drawer/Modal Focus management. To resolve, use the disableEnforceFocus property to drawer/modal. When set to true, it lets the drawer lose focus, making input possible.

However, note this might affect accessibility for screen readers. Proceed thoughtfully.

here is the code snippet -

```html
<Drawer id="drawer" anchor="right" open={true} **disableEnforceFocus**
}}>
    {
    <MyComponent/>//Inside this component i have sweetalert
    }
</Drawer>
```

I hope same property will resolve issue in case of MUI Modal.

Answer (score 0):

For someone running on bootstrap@5.1.3 I solved this by set focus option to false on Modal object.
Something like

```
const containerClaimReqModal = document.getElementById("claim-request-detail-modal");
const claimReqModal = new bootstrap.Modal(containerClaimReqModal,{focus:false});
```

as docs references https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#options

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4:

```js
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {};
```